# Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.4 Hangs While Restarting

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, freeze, reboot

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 inside a VirtualBox VM. My Ubuntu hangs very often, possibly every single restart it seems, although it wasn't like this before. When this happens, I can force a VM reset, and then Ubuntu boots normally.

How can I diagnose this issue? Is there a log file where Ubuntu would note what caused a restart to hang?

[image: Screen it hangs on]